# PHP calculate percentages

Tags: php, percentage

I need some help. It's a simple code, but I don't have idea how to write in down. I have the numbers:

```
$NumberOne = 500;
$NumberTwo = 430;
$NumberThree = 150;
$NumberFour = 30;
```

At all this is:

```
$Everything = 1110; // all added
```

Now I want to show what percentage is for example $NumberFour of everything or what percentage is $NumberTwo of $Everything. So the "market share".

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you find that you're numbering variables, then you should probably be using an array instead

Comment: Hint: Percentage is `(part/total) * 100`.

Comment: [demo](http://ideone.com/okUvZ3)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use some simple maths: divide the number you wish to find the percentage for by the total and multiply by 100.

Example:

```
$total = 250;
$portion = 50;
$percentage = ($portion / $total) * 100; // 20
```

### Solution to original example

To get `$NumberFour` as a percentage of the total amount you'd use:

```
$percentage = ($NumberFour / $Everything) * 100;
```

### Rounding

Depending on the numbers you're working with, you may want to round the resulting percentage. In my initial example, we get 20% which is a nice round number. The original question however uses 1110 as the total and 30 as the number to calculate the percentage for (2.70270...).

PHP's built in `round()` function could be useful when working with percentages for display: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

```
echo round($percentage, 2) . '%'; // 2.7% -- (30 / 1110) * 100 rounded to 2dp
```

### Helper Functions

I would only contemplate creating helper functions when their use justifies it (if calculating and displaying a percentage isn't a one-off). I've attached an example below tying together everything from above.

```
function format_percentage($percentage, $precision = 2) {
    return round($percentage, $precision) . '%';
}

function calculate_percentage($number, $total) {

    // Can't divide by zero so let's catch that early.
    if ($total == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($number / $total) * 100;
}

function calculate_percentage_for_display($number, $total) {
    return format_percentage(calculate_percentage($number, $total));
}

echo calculate_percentage_for_display(50, 250); // 20%
echo calculate_percentage_for_display(30, 1110); // 2.7%
echo calculate_percentage_for_display(75, 190); // 39.47%
```

Answer (score 7):

Create function to calculate percentage between two numbers.

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculate percetage between the numbers
 */

function percentageOf( $number, $everything, $decimals = 2 ){
    return round( $number / $everything * 100, $decimals );
}

$numbers = array( 500, 430, 150, 30 );
$everything = array_sum( $numbers );

echo 'First of everything: '.percentageOf( $numbers[0], $everything )."%\n";
echo 'Second of everything: '.percentageOf( $numbers[1], $everything )."%\n";
echo 'Third of everything: '.percentageOf( $numbers[2], $everything )."%\n";
echo 'Fourth of everything: '.percentageOf( $numbers[3], $everything )."%\n";

?>
```

This outputs

```
First of everything: 45.05%
Second of everything: 38.74%
Third of everything: 13.51%
Fourth of everything: 2.7%
```

Comment: $numbers = array( 500, 200, 500, 200,100 );
 for this array, the total percentage sum is not equal 100, but 99.99 .its always .01 shortage

Comment: @RockersTechnology It depends. It could be, yes, because it's rounding to two decimals. You can always show more decimals

Comment: @RockersTechnology yeah, you are basically chopping parts from each calculation using rounding. So, getting 0.01 short is not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can also come up with the percentage with the following formula. For the percentage, add a 0. in front of it.  So 5% would be 0.05.  Total X 0.05 is the amount.

Comment: It's same to the answers above. If I want to get 10% of x, I'll multiply it with 0.1.